# Entity Framework Core - the property 'Post.Videos' is of type 'List<string>' which is not supported by the current database provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on an ASP.NET Core project. I am trying to add jsonb column to my table.

I got this error

> The property 'Post.Videos' is of type 'List' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type, or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

post.cs

```
public List<string> Images { get; set; }    // jsonb
public List<string> Videos { get; set; } // jsonb
```

PostConfiguration.cs

```
builder.Property(i => i.Images)
            .HasColumnType("jsonb");

builder.Property(i => i.Videos)
            .HasColumnType("jsonb");
```

Why does this error occur? What is wrong with my configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does not support list of string. You can  create an  other entity  or convert your stringlist to string

```
public class SomeObj
    {
        public SomeObj()
        {
            this.Pics = new List<Pic>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Pic> Pics { get; set; }        
    }
    public class Pic
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Picstring { get; set; }

        public int SomeObjId { get; set; }
        public SomeObj SomeObj{ get; set; }
    }
    public class Video
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Picstring { get; set; }
        public int SomeObjId { get; set; }
        public SomeObj SomeObj { get; set; }
    }
```